# WPF button text scrolling on mouse over

Tags: wpf, button, text, scroll

is it possible for buttons that have longer Content(text) than the max button width to kinda scroll the remaining text from right to left on mouse over? something like an electronic banner is the best I could explain it.

as of now this is the only thing that reflects my button style xaml.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Str" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90"/>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  That's usually called marquee.

You can template a wpf control to do just about anything.

Put a canvas in there and a textblock. Animate the canvas.Left of the textblock.
There's a marquee implementation here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx?Redirected=true#Marquee

You would, obviously, want to start the animation using a datatrigger and ismouseover true.

Comment: thanks for the response. So if I have like 20 buttons already created, no way to alter my code now unless I modify all of them to include a textblock in the xaml. correct? that would be a huge hasle...

Comment: Incorrect. You can re template via a style and apply that to all or some buttons.

Comment: added some code. anything I could do with what I have? checked the marquee implementation article, but I fail to see any common grounds :(